# Xamarin caused by: Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException

Tags: xamarin.forms

I received that exception in my Xamarin.Forms App (Android, HTC Desire 510) on `OS Android: 4.1.2`but it's not very expressive and I don't know where to start investigation:

> Xamarin caused by: Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException:
>   Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4174fee8 is not
>   valid; is your activity running?   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x0000c] in :0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallVoidMethod
>   (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo
>   method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x00084] in
>   :0    at
>   Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualVoidMethod
>   (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self,
>   Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0002f] in
>   :0    at Android.App.Dialog.Show ()
>   [0x0000a] in <79e6945a2f4a4e2f844e36c860dfb012>:0    at
>   Acr.UserDialogs.UserDialogsImpl+<>c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0 ()
>   [0x00011] in <435daf83b740428697641f6937603702>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x0000b] in
>   <79e6945a2f4a4e2f844e36c860dfb012>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in <79e6945a2f4a4e2f844e36c860dfb012>:0    at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object:c03c2323-76c4-49c2-96eb-2a4f82e62e78 (intptr,intptr)

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Eric